# Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unsupported Schema element found http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attributeGroup. At: 222:42

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

> Error: Failed to parse wsdl: Unsupported Schema element found http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attributeGroup. At: 222:42

I am getting the following error while parsing WSDL .

```
  <xsd:attributeGroup name="commonAtts">
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative because I haven't got any
.

Comment: If the service you are trying to use supports a REST/JSON API use that instead. The WSDL tooling in Apex has a number of limitations and working around them can get tricky right up to and including [hand-coding web service calls](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/when-generate-from-wsdl-fails-hand-coding-web-service-calls/).

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky can you share the WSDL in question? It is sometimes possible to work around these limitations. Particularly if the problem is on an element that you aren't going to use anyway.